# Is it possible to listen for object visibility change in python?

Tags: python, outliner, depsgraph

Is it possible to listen to changes in object visibility via a Python add-on in Blender?

Being a beginner, I only know of listing all objects and doing `obj.hide_get()`, but I at least know that doing that in a loop is very bad.

Comment: The next less bad thing would be a modal timer operator (maybe with 0.2s). The probably best option would be the [depsgraph_update_post](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.handlers.html#bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_post) handler.

Comment: Depending on what you want to do with the information, ie modify another object's properties, you could use a driver

Comment: maybe this can help which uses `depsgraph_update_post` https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/283247/how-to-trigger-a-script-after-completing-object-transform/

Answer (score 2):

I had a [similar query](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/283773/script-to-that-triggers-update-whenever-an-objects-visibility-has-change) and here's the updated script that will print out a check of what has changed in visibility using [`depsgraph_update_post`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.handlers.html#bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_post) application handler:

```
import bpy

def on_visibility_change(obj):
    print("visiblity changed for object:", obj.name)

def on_depsgraph_update(scene):
    global previous_visible_states
    states = set(o.name for o in bpy.context.scene.objects if o.hide_viewport or o.hide_render or o.hide_get())
    for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects:
        changed = obj.name not in states and obj.name in previous_visible_states
        if changed or (obj.name in states and obj.name not in previous_visible_states):
            on_visibility_change(obj)
    previous_visible_states = states

bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_post.clear()
bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_post.append(on_depsgraph_update)
previous_visible_states = set(o.name for o in bpy.context.scene.objects if o.hide_viewport or o.hide_render or o.hide_get())
```